# How to connect xmpp server using TSL/SSL?

Tags: xmpp, smack

i am using smack 4.2.1 to connect xmpp server ,but when i run the code ,the server response the message below.
i really know that the error caused by tsl/ssl config.but i dont know how to solve.

```
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                 .setXmppDomain("404.city").setUsernameAndPassword("xx", "xxxx")
                 .setCompressionEnabled(false)
                 .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)                   
                 .build();
             XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
             connection.connect();
```

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1060)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:982)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:998)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

i fix it by myself....
i should set a SSLContext to the config

Comment: can you please share how you set the sslContetext ?